# "Freeze" askers' edit/update privileges for a short period after asking a question on Meta

Tags: discussion, meta, new-users, behavior

We had already discussed at length ideas about hiding downvotes/upvotes etc. and I realize why a lot of the previous suggestions to hide/modify the downvote view was faulty.

But another idea sort of hit me, and it's the idea of temporarily "freezing" a user's (probably a new or sub-1000 user) ability to both get feedback and update the page.

**Why?**

Well, I think we've all seen that when a new user, call him Joe123, asks a question, he will rather quickly receive feedback. The feedback is staggered, but it's fast.

So in the first minute, he gets one pointed comment. Then after a few seconds, another comment, directly countering him.

Soon, Joe123 is arguing back and forth about *why* he had a great idea. And in his mind, it really is very good and he's embittered that people are disagreeing.

But how about this: we freeze Joe123 for *only 5 minutes*. *[ or 1, 2, 10 , etc]*

If we froze Joe123 for 5 minutes, he gets up and has a coffee. He pauses, reflects, etc..

In the meantime, many people comment, vote, etc.

When Joe123 is back, he sees it all at once. And he is likely to feel overwhelmed and will certainly be forced to digest it before countering.

The benefit is that it :

1. prevents extra arguments (i.e. it *should* do that)
2. encourages the user to factor in the "blind spot"

I realize that technically this is much added complexity. Just a discussion really. The idea is to keep everything *the exact same* except put in a sizable lag for the user. I realize it's hard to implement, but I'm curious if it might theoretically help (it's somewhat similar to masking votes in first 30 minutes à la AskReddit).

Comment: Users not responding to feedback on their questions is the problem, not the solution.

Comment: @DavidRobinson - Would you give them 5 minutes? ;-)

Comment: If we freeze Joe for five minutes, he comes back and has lots of things to reply to, all BAM! at once. That makes it *harder*. Not easier. Basically; your proposal *forces Joe to wait*, and be hit by everything at once. What do you have against Joe? ;-)

Comment: @AndrewBarber - Well - I don't trust Joe, he might be a troublemaker! hmm shall I rename my protagonist ;)

Comment: Oh, no... Joe *is* a troublemaker. But we should suspend him, not rate-limit his commenting.

Comment: I hope Joe isn't drinking decaf, otherwise he would not be able to respond to every incoming comment in a swift manner.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If a user posts a question which obviously has problems, I see no reason why they should not either defend or correct their viewpoints immediately. I want to be able to give people feedback, and have them respond, both as soon as possible.

The problem lies not with users thinking their content is good, but with users *not caring* about the quality of their content.

Additionally, I'm not sure there's much benefit in seeing all of the responses at once. Typically, there won't be more than one response anyway. Remember, if other users see that something has been said, they likely won't bother to reiterate it.

Comment: good points, I do agree in the whole.. though I am personally curious about how things might play out if we were to experiment to time . It seems there's *some* possibility of bending user behavior through time-controls

Answer (score 4):

I see your idea, and it has merit, however the cons outweigh the pros by too many for it to be viable here.

**Pros**
The only real pro is the idea you suggested.

Joe123 comes back and reads the slander, constructive criticism, people agreeing, and many reasons for and against all in one go.
Digests it all and starts to see reasoning with some of the arguments against their idea/question.

His replies might be more constructive with the knowledge of said practical arguments than they might have been if he'd just answered each comment as they're posted.

I have seen plenty of times where someone is arguing blind against comments, and then someone comes along and in a quite simple sentence makes it all clear to them why they're talking cobblers, and the penny drops.
Had they read all comments first the enlightening comment would avoid an onslaught of debating.

---

**Cons**
If I ask a question or propose something I deserve the right to join in discussions arguably *more* than others as it's my question.

> If we froze Joe123 for 5 minutes, he gets up and has a coffee. He pauses, reflects, etc..

Or..
If we froze Joe123 for 5 minutes, he gets up and has a coffee, the caffeine-effect takes it's course and J-J-J-OOOEE123 *twitch one-eye-wink-wink-wink* is now *quite keen* to start typing various replies to each and everyone who posted, regardless of constructive criticism or not.

Joe123 likely wont even read them all, and just replies one by one with @ down the list of comments, regardless of if further down there's one which would enlighten him why his idea/issue is not such a doozy as he thought.

Joe123 might read them all, digest it, and still the penny does not drop and then writes replies to everyone as he would have without the time delay.

This is Meta, and questioners and answerers are free to debate as much as needed.

Often there is no black and white answer and so the discussion between questioner and answerers needs to be live to allow discussions to naturally be directed to certain viewpoints.

If there is no black/white answer, then the discussions will be out of sync and crappy for others reading through them going back and forth (happens a bit now, but not a lot considering).

**The main con** is while you remove the immediate ability from the questioner to be able to counter objective comments (or, argue blindly), you simply pass it to the people commenting.
As numerous people can simply bash out negative comments without the questioner being able to reply to counter their comment, and as with your logic that a questioner might not have thought of something, so might a trend in people's replies that the questioner can no longer point out.

In that scenario, they'll just edit their question to reflect what would have been replies in comments. Which is worse...

---

Again, I see your idea is valid and has merit, and I certainly see what you're trying to resolve, but this isn't the resolve to it. In fact, I don't think there is a resolve to what you're trying to fix, or even a feature that could ease it..

People *often* do not grasp the logic of a counter argument to their proposal/question/complaint. They're annoyed/confused/perturbed at the issue they posted about,  or are joyous/excited of posting what they believed was the most fantastic idea on Stack since it allowed downvotes on answers.

People can be very closed minded, or blinded by their own thoughts or belief in their idea, stubborn to new ideas, etc.
You could postpone their ability to respond for 3 hours, with half the Stack user base responding with the same comment, they'd still counter it...